# Why in implication, if premise is false then implication is true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I am not able to understand implication well. I can see If in $P \implies Q$, if Pis true and Q is false then implication is false. But i cannot understand other cases where it is taken as true. Is this just a convention ? or some underlying reasoning behind it

Thanks

Comment: You may find my recent blog posting useful. There I 
 derive, among other things from self-evident, elementary properties of various logical connectives in classical logic, that $\neg A \implies [A \implies B]$ as well the usual "defintion" of implication $A\implies B \iff \neg [A \land \neg B]$ http://www.dcproof.com/IfPigsCanFly.html

Comment: @DanChristensen Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The essence of implication is that when $P\implies Q$, we cannot have $P\text{ true}$ and $Q\text{ false}$. No other case if "forbidden", i.e. creates a contradiction.

For instance, with $x>1\implies x>0$, there are no $x$ such that $x>1\land x\le0$ ($\text{true}\implies\text{false}$). But $x\le1\land x>0$ ($\text{false}\implies\text{true}$) and $x\le1\land x\le0$ ($\text{false}\implies\text{false}$) are quite possible.

---

The instances such that $P$ is $\text{false}$ are usually uninteresting/meaningless and create a paradox called "ex falso quodlibet".

For instance

$$x>x+1\implies x^2<0$$ and

$$x>x+1\implies \pi=2$$ are said *vacuously true* implications (which are perfectly valid implications), because no $x$ can invalidate them.

Comment: i don't understand what you are trying to convey in 3rd and 4th lines

Comment: @JessicaJeffery $\text{false}\implies\text{false}$ is always a valid implication, despite apparent absurdness. Same for $\text{false}\implies\text{true}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a definition of the implication (two argument) function.

It has a sense: we obtain the consequences of true assumptions. Similarly as in our life: If there was no gravity I could jump from the Eiffel Tower and survive.

Comment: Hi, seen you after a long time. You used to answer my questions in 2014

Comment: @JessicaJeffery It is nice that you remember this. I am going to check history of my answers. :-)

Comment: Lovely conversation

Comment: I fail to see in what way this example explains the definition.

Comment: @YvesDaoust If your assume that because the implication is valid, you can jump, you will die. (And erroneuos understanding of the implication is a typical mistake of students).

Comment: So you are explaining in what way mathematical and "daily life" implications differ. Following the mathematical definition, you live and you die are both compatible with the implication (on Earth). I don't think this clarifies the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If Q is false and P is true, this contradicts the fact that "if P then Q". Since "P is true" and "if P then Q" tells us that Q must be true. Thus, P must be false.